# Linux Mandriva: Tomcat can not get MySQL database connection, why?

Tags: mysql, linux, jakarta-ee, tomcat, networking

I installed **Tomcat 7** and **MySQL** database on **Linux Mandriva**, but the application is deployed in the container can not get a connection.

I wrote two simple tests, and when to run them from the client, I get the connection -

```
public class TestHibernate {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("userName");
        user.setPassword("userPassword");

        Session session = HibernateUtil.
            getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
    }
}
```

Part of HibernateUtil -

```
...
      cnf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/gibrid");
      cnf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "java");
      cnf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "java");
...
```

Jdbc test -

```
public class TestJdbc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Connection conn = null;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/";
      String dbName = "gibrid";
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String userName = "java"; 
      String password = "java";
      try {
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
          System.out.println("Connected to the database");
          conn.close();
          System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

In these cases, I get a connection and can work with the database. But when I request from the client browser, I get a timeout. Why is that? 
I would be very grateful for the information.

---

Here is the **catalina.out** -

```
...
    INFO: Server startup in 5315 ms
    17.10.2012 15:36:52 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
    INFO: Requested resource [VAADIN/themes/web13theme/favicon.ico] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
    17.10.2012 15:36:58 com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
    INFO: Requested resource [VAADIN/themes/projtheme/img/cancel.png] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
    3 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
    25 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.0.SP1
    39 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
    44 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
    50 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
    148 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
    176 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
    247 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.ssi.domen.Incoming
    313 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.ssi.domen.Incoming on table INCOMING
    397 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.ssi.domen.Outcoming
    397 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.ssi.domen.Outcoming on table OUTCOMING
    400 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.ssi.domen.User
    400 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.ssi.domen.User on table USER
    402 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.ssi.domen.Cable
    402 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.ssi.domen.Cable on table CABLE
    497 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
    509 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    510 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
    510 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
    514 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://---ip here----/gibrid
    514 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=java, password=****}
    189691 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
    com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

    ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

    java.net.ConnectException
    MESSAGE: Connection timed out

    STACKTRACE:

    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at com.ssi.hbnutils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:34)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.check(RegWindow.java:167)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.insert(RegWindow.java:140)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.access$0(RegWindow.java:139)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow$1.buttonClick(RegWindow.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:567)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:223)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1460)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1404)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1329)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:761)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:323)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)


    ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



    Last packet sent to the server was 6 ms ago.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at com.ssi.hbnutils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:34)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.check(RegWindow.java:167)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.insert(RegWindow.java:140)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.access$0(RegWindow.java:139)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow$1.buttonClick(RegWindow.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:567)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:223)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1460)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1404)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1329)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:761)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:323)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    190005 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    190066 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
    190090 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
    190092 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
    190092 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
    190114 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: disabled
    190115 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
    190116 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
    190125 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
    190127 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
    190127 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
    190128 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
    190128 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
    190129 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    190167 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    190169 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
    190169 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
    190170 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
    190171 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
    190171 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
    190173 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
    190174 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
    190239 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
    190250 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
    190250 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
    190260 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
    190260 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
    190761 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
    191112 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
    380252 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
    380252 [http-bio-8081-exec-7] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

    ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

    java.net.ConnectException
    MESSAGE: Connection timed out

    STACKTRACE:

    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1353)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.check(RegWindow.java:168)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.insert(RegWindow.java:140)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow.access$0(RegWindow.java:139)
        at com.ssi.windows.RegWindow$1.buttonClick(RegWindow.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:567)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:223)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1460)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1404)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1329)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:761)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:323)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)


    ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



    Last packet sent to the server was 5 ms ago.
```

Comment: First look into the log files. What happens there?

Comment: How do you connect from Tomcat to Mysql ? Do you use a JNDI connection pool, or directly using pure JDBC?

Comment: If you run mysql and tomcat on the same host, set `localhost` instead of `ip` in `HibernateUtils` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Hibernate, so I don't know if this is relevant:

"hibernate.properties not found"

"using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://---ip here----/gibrid"

Is the IP **and** port the same as in your test programs?

This [blog](http://hibernatedb.blogspot.de/2009/04/hibernate-and-mysql-connection-timeouts.html) hints at configuration problems with C3PO. One comment hints at different timeout settings between Mysql and C3PO. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Editing your mysql configuration file to bind on 0.0.0.0 or your ip instead of 127.0.0.1 might work.